# Heroku + Error occured while executing heroku run rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, migration, rake

I am trying to deploy a sample app at Heroku. Whole code is pushed to heroku.

Now i am running a 'heroku run rake' command to create db and one table at heroku. But I am getting some error.

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly"

I am not getting th way to resolve it.

**Rails Console:**

[image: Rails Console]

**database.yml**

[image: Database.yml]

Comment: Doesn't sound like this has anything to do with your app - sounds like it's an issue with Heroku.  Maybe try again in a few minutes?

Comment: Actually I am trying this from last 3 days but no success.

Comment: This doesn't look like a heroku issue at all, the stack trace is from a Windows installed Ruby and Heroku doesn't provide windows machines. also, the command is `heroku run rake db:migrate`. There is probably something else wrong with your machine that is causing this.

Comment: We usually see this on slower connections, if ever. May I ask how fast your connection is?

Comment: 100 Kbs download speed ..